# Populate a datagrid view of another form using a main form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, entity-framework-6, populate

I have two windows forms in my project. Fist one is Main and the second one is Lookup. Lookup has a datagridview controller. I'm trying to open the Lookup window and load the datagridview of it in a key leave event of a text box in main form. Though Lookup form opens in key leave event it the datagridview doesn't get populated. 
This is what I tried.
Main form keyleave event.

```
 if (e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.F3))
            {
                foreach (Form frm in Application.OpenForms)
                {
                    if (frm is FormControllers.Lookup)
                    {

                        if (frm.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
                            frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                        frm.Focus();
                        return;
                    }
                }
                DataGridView dgvtopass = new DataGridView();
                using(DataControllers.RIT_Allocation_Entities RAEntity  = new DataControllers.RIT_Allocation_Entities())
                {
                    dgvtopass.DataSource = RAEntity.TBLM_PRODUCT.ToList<DataControllers.TBLM_PRODUCT>();
                }

                FormControllers.Lookup newLookUp = new FormControllers.Lookup(dgvtopass);

                newLookUp.ShowDialog(this);
            }
        }
    }
```

Code in the lookup form

```
public partial class Lookup : Form
    {
        private DataGridView dgvDataCallingForm;
        public Lookup(DataGridView dgvDataCallingForm)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.dgvDataCallingForm= dgvDataCallingForm;

        }

        private void Lookup_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.dgvLookup.DataSource = dgvDataCallingForm;
        }
    }
```

How to populate the grid of look up form ?

Comment: A `DataGridView` is not a `DataSource`. Why don't you just pass `TBLM_PRODUCT` to the new form?

Comment: @Crowcoder What do you mean, is it just to populate the datagrid view using TBLM_product on formload event of it? can you just show an example ?

Comment: You are setting the `DataSource` of a grid to a grid. You could probably get away with `this.dgvLookup.DataSource = dgvDataCallingForm.DataSource;` but I would never advocate passing UI controls around like that.

Comment: @Crowcoder What  are the disadvanges of passing UI controls around like that?

Comment: It's a code smell. The grid is a reference type and any changes you make to it's properties are going to reflect back on the parent form. Also, you don't even use the grid, you just use it as a vessel for the data. That's a misuse in my opinion.

Comment: @chathwind Also, a general rule when passing data is to pass then in the least specialized form you can think of. In other words: allow the receiver of the data to know as little as possible so they've got maximum flexibility. You *could* so `this.dgvLookup.DataSource = dgvDataCallingForm.DataSource` but then, what's the use of creating this redundant (and expensive!) DGV? You may as well pass the data source only, i.e. the `TBLM_PRODUCT` list. That said, WinForms and data is a whole subject of its own. Consider using view models, to start with.